# Pattern Navigation controller select controller - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have this scenario:

[image]

I have a navigation controller within a view controller with table view and varius cells.
When cell is tapped, I go to another view controller (with "TEST" label text for testing).

My problem is this:

My app can be able to open from URL and in its query string there is a param that indicate which controller have to open (that with the table view or that with label).

I cant to find a pattern for to achive this in "clean" way.

For example:

I receive an URL with query param that indicate that I have to open the controller with label.

How can I organize the code to indicate that you must first go to the controller with the table and simulate the cell tap then go to the final controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every navigation controller has array of view controllers. In case that you need to add both view controllers you can use next solution:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[controllers addObject:tableVC];
[controllers addObject:labelVC];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```

This will animate labelVC without the tableVc becoming visible in the process. When the user press the back button, he will be returned to the tableVC